# Using pattern matching to match an array with a non-zero lower bound

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, pattern-matching, excel-automation

I'm writing code that calls Excel macros via COM Automation. There is a need to handle different return types and pattern matching is perfect for that:

```cs
var result = ExcelApp.Run("MyMacro", ...);

return result switch
{
    object[,] array => ...,
    string message => ...,
    _ => throw new MyException("...")
};
```

Because it's Excel the arrays have a lower bound of 1 instead of 0 and this is fully supported in .NET. However, to my surprise I have discovered that when I try to perform pattern matching of a one-dimensional array with a lower bound of 1 the pattern doesn't match.

To elaborate, creating a 2×2 array with lower bounds of 1 will match the pattern `object[,]`, i.e. the following statement is `true`:

```cs
Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 2, 2 }, new[] { 1, 1 }) is object[,] array
```

However, creating a 1×2 array (just a normal array with two elements) with a lower bound of 1 (which is not normal) will **not** match the pattern `object[]`, i.e. the following statement is `false`:

```cs
Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 2 }, new[] { 1 }) is object[] array
```

This is surprising to me but is there a pattern that can be used to match a one-dimensional array with a non-zero lower bound?

Answer (score 3):

It's odd that the rules for pattern matching arrays are different for one-dimensional arrays but because the array has a `Rank` property it's still possible:

```cs
return result switch
{
    Array { Rank: 1 } array => ...,
    // ... other cases
};
```

In case you want to convert the 1-based array (matched in `array` above) into a normal 0-based array it can be done like this:

```cs
array.Cast<object>().ToArray()
```

Because the lower bound isn't exposed as a property and instead requires a method call (`GetLowerBound()`) you can't pattern match on a specific lower bound.